# How to make activiti show textarea field instaded of text input?

Tags: activiti

How can I make activiti show textarea field instaded of text input for formProperty below?

```
<extensionElements>
        <activiti:formProperty id="Ata"
        name="Ata"
        required="true"
        type="string" />
    </extensionElements>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Extend the `AbstractFormType` class and override it's methods as shown in this example [TextAreaFormType.java](http://code.google.com/p/activitiinaction/source/browse/trunk/book-explorer-form/src/main/java/org/bpmnwithactiviti/explorer/form/TextAreaFormType.java)
2. Activiti Explorer is implemented in Vaadin so the form field also has to be implemented using Vaadin. [Here](http://code.google.com/p/activitiinaction/source/browse/trunk/book-explorer-form/src/main/java/org/bpmnwithactiviti/explorer/form/TextAreaFormPropertyRenderer.java)  you can find sample implementation
3. Add a custom form type to the process engine configuration in `applicationContext.xml`
   [applicationContext.xml](http://code.google.com/p/activitiinaction/source/browse/trunk/book-explorer-form/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml)

---

```
<bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration">
<property name="customFormTypes">
<list>
<ref bean="userFormType"/>
<ref bean="textAreaFormType"/>
</list>
</property>
</bean>
<bean id="userFormType" class="org.activiti.explorer.form.UserFormType"/>
<bean id="textAreaFormType" class="org.bpmnwithactiviti.explorer.form.TextAreaFormType"/>
```

Comment: I have done it but I am getting error, look at  https://gist.github.com/dextervip/5136407

Comment: <bean id="processEngineConfiguration"> is  already defined in  activiti-standalone-context.xml so edit it instead  applicationContext.xml

Comment: I changed and resolved that issue, however I get "No property renderer found for type: textarea" https://gist.github.com/dextervip/5145307

Comment: Ahh you have missed adding his PropertyRenderer in activiti-ui-context.xml, now works. Thanks :)