# Activiti form data types?

Tags: activiti

What are the available form types available for use in an Activiti workflow form?

I could not find in [the documentation](http://www.activiti.org/userguide/index.html#formProperties).

*Example of an Activiti workflow form (with various types):*

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"[We support the following form property types:](http://www.activiti.org/userguide/index.html#formProperties)"

- string (org.activiti.engine.impl.form.StringFormType)
- long (org.activiti.engine.impl.form.LongFormType)
- enum (org.activiti.engine.impl.form.EnumFormType)
- date (org.activiti.engine.impl.form.DateFormType)
- boolean (org.activiti.engine.impl.form.BooleanFormType)

Comment: +1 Thanks! I thought `user` could be a type too, but I was probably mistaken.

Comment: you can extend available Activiti-explorer form types 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331195/how-to-make-activiti-show-textarea-field-instaded-of-text-input

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, `user` is another form-type which is supported by the Activiti Explorer and by the REST-API. If you use the user form-property, Activiti Explorer will provide an auto-complete field to select a user. This also works if you use an LDAP or Active Directory. In this way, you can determine assignees during the process runtime. A group form-property is still missing. In addition to the user form-property, you can use the data types mentioned above.